# rsync appears to copy files to Android device, but no files are actually copied

Tags: usb, android, rsync

I've attached my Android device with a USB cable to my computer and set its USB mode to data transfer.

I am trying to keep my music directory on my MicroSD on my Android device in sync with my computer music directory using this rsync command:

```bsh
rsync -rvOih --delete --ignore-existing --verbose --progress --no-perms /home/username/external/Music/ /path/to/android/filesystem/Music/
```

I get good output from this command, e.g.:

```
>f+++++++++ Modest Mouse/[1997] The Lonesome Crowded West/06 - Doin' The Cockroach.mp3
          6.21M 100%    5.64MB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#64, ir-chk=1012/2309)
```

When I actually check the music directory on the Android device, I can see the directories for this music have been created (i.e. `/path/to/android/filesystem/Modest Mouse/[1997] The Lonesome Crowded West/` exists), however none of the mp3 files are present.

It may be worth mentioning I am mounting the Android device by opening nautlius and simply clicking on it in the sidebar.

I'm quite confused why this might be happening; any help is very much appreciated. I haven't manage to find anyone else with this problem so far...

Comment: See if the problem gets solved after running the [sync](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) command in your terminal. It flushes all the I/O buffers in the memory to disk(s) .

Comment: This does not fix the problem, unfortunately

Comment: This not the solution for rsync but you can use [GSConnect](https://www.maketecheasier.com/connect-android-gnome-desktop-gsconnect/) or [KDEConnect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) to transfer your files . I personally use KDEConnect and moving files between my computer and mobile phone via USB is now somehow obsolete for me. Although USB would be faster than using a LAN network but this is very handy.

Comment: what is -rvOih supposed to achieve? Looking at the man page, I don't see that switch https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: -r = recursive, -v = verbose, -O = omit file times, -i and -h are something to do with readability I think. -O and --no-perms are necessary to copy to the Android filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't solve your problem regarding `rsync` but you can use [GSConenct](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/) if you use ubuntu with gnome shell or [KDEConnect](https://kdeconnect.kde.org/) if you use KDE plasma (you can use KDEConnect in gnome but it is better integrated with KDE plasma) to transfer your files between your PC and mobile phone ( unfortunately KDEConnect only works with android phones for now)

KDEConnect has lot more features and is well-integrated with the dolphin file manager (i.e default file manager in KDE plasma) and it puts an option named `Send to "Your phone name" via KDE Connect` in the drop down menu when you right click almost any file .( Note that you need the [Android version of KDE Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en_US) in your phone .)

Take a look at [The demo video](https://peertube.mastodon.host/videos/watch/f8ffd8de-3df5-46b5-bbe3-114393be4b44).

If anybody has a better solution I'm glad to hear.